# Find distinct rows based on combination of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having trouble finding a good solution to a problem in SQL.

Say I have table like this:

```
ID    | A   |   A
--------------------
4427  | 2   |   3
4427  | 3   |   2
4427  | 3   |   5
4427  | 5   |   3
4427  | 1   |   3
4427  | 2   |   5
4427  | 3   |   1
```

Now I want to find the rows with a unique combination of ID and A. By this I mean that I only want to see the rows where the combination of A(1) and A(2) exists only once. For example the first two rows in the table is "the same" since the combination of 2 and 3 is the same as 3 and 2.

The expected result to my quesion would be:

```
ID    | A   |   A
--------------------
4427  | 2   |   3
4427  | 3   |   5
4427  | 1   |   3
4427  | 2   |   5
```

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Why you choose (2,3) instead of (3,2)?

Comment: @JoeTaras -> Doesn't make a difference for me if it is (2,3) or (3,2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this would be a simple "distinct" query if you ALWAYS had the ColA with a value less then ColB.  Given this, you can use a case statement to handle this, combined with a distinct operator.

Try this.

```
Select  Distinct
        ID,
        Case When ColA < ColB Then ColA Else ColB End,
        Case When ColA < ColB Then ColB Else ColA End
From    YourTableHere
```

Comment: The table is a self-join, so the combination will always exist in both columns. This works like a charm.

Comment: I don't know anything about your process (overall goal), but is it possible to modify the self join code to look something like this...  Table As X Join Table As Y On X.Id = Y.Id and X.ColA < Y.ColA

Comment: Yeah this works perfectly as well - actually a more simple solution, thanks. This is primary a one-time thing, but I had too many rows to go through if I had to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this. FYI, the output A1/A2 may have differnet order than original value. If you don't care the order, you may try this.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ID,A1 AS A, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A1,A2) AS rn FROM Table1
UNION ALL
  SELECT ID,A2 AS A, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A1,A2) AS rn FROM Table1
)
SELECT DISTINCT ID, MIN(A) AS A1, MAX(A) AS A2
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID, rn
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1379/5)